# Concatenating char arrays together

Tags: c++, concatenation, strcpy, strncpy

This is something I would have considered trivial several years ago... It's been awhile since I've dabbled in C or C++ and I'm having an issue that is now causing a migraine.

I am receiving an error for the following code:

```
CompressFile::CompressFile(wchar_t *WorkingDirectory, wchar_t *File)
{
    int bzipError = BZ_OK;

    wprintf(L"Attempting to compress %s%s\n", WorkingDirectory, File);

    wchar_t FileRawInput[MAX_PATH];
    wcsncpy(FileRawInput, WorkingDirectory, sizeof(FileRawInput));
    wcsncat(FileRawInput, File, sizeof(FileRawInput));

    wchar_t bzipCompressedOutput[MAX_PATH];
    wcsncpy(bzipCompressedOutput, FileRawInput, sizeof(bzipCompressedOutput));
    wcscat(bzipCompressedOutput, L".bz2"); 

    wprintf(L"Output of string bzip: %s\n", bzipCompressedOutput);
    wprintf(L"Output of string raw: %s\n", FileRawInput);
}
```

I am receiving this the following error on line 8:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x64F4C6D1 in ias-agent.exe: 0xC00001A5: An invalid exception handler routine has been detected (parameters: 0x00000003).
```

I've already gone the distance to avoid using the `string` class, and I'd like to keep it that way for the time being. All I am trying to do, is add two strings together for `RawFileInput` and then add the value of `RawFileInput` to `bzipCompressionOutput` and finally, concatenate `.bz2` to the end of `bzipCompressionOutput`.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `std::wstring`?

Comment: If you want to avoid using C++, then you can always tag this question as C

Comment: If you need a modifiable `wchar` buffer, use `std::vector`, otherwise, use `std::wstring`. This C-style string business is a waste of your precious time. (As always, unless you can proof a significant advantage, but that seems unlikely in this case.)

Comment: The final parameter for `wcsncpy` and `wcsncat` should be the number of characters (i.e. `wchar_t`s) to copy, not the size measured in `char`s.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you. That fixed my issue.

Comment: You tagged this as C++.  Compare what is posted to [this](http://rextester.com/RKSUIT62212).  No buffer overruns, no fiddling around with `sizeof` to mess things up, and is guaranteed to work correctly.

Comment: A number of issues: first, you're calling `wcsncpy` and passing `sizeof(...)` which gives you the number of *bytes* in the buffer and which is wrong: the function takes the number of *characters* in the buffer, so you want `sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])`. Second, this smells like stack corruption to me, so I'll ask the obvious: are you 100% sure that `WorkingDirectory` and `File` fit into `MAX_PATH` characters? If they don't, `wcsncpy` will not null-terminate `FileRawInput` which could cause "weird" crashes. You should avoid `wcsncpy` like the plague...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [last page of chapter 4 in his book](https://books.google.com/books?id=PSUNAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA110#v=onepage&q&f=false): "The C++ Programming Language" [Bjarne Stroustrup the creator of C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) says:

> Prefer `strings` over C-style strings

It's only advice but I'd encourage you to follow it.

---

But your real problem is that you're stomping memory there are *not* `sizeof(FileRawInput)` `wchar_t`s in your `FileRawInput` likewise there are not `sizeof(bzipCompressedOutput)` in `bzipCompressedOutput` array, there are `MAX_PATH` `wchar_t`s in both. The problem is that `sizeof` will tell you the number of bytes in your array, but if each element is larger than 1 byte then you have incorrectly told `wcsncpy` and `wscncat` your character count. A `wchar_t` is generally 2 bytes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx Meaning you're calling effectively `wcsncpy(FileRawInput, WorkingDirectory, 200)`. Stomping memory 100 `wchar_t`s beyond what you have allocated. Correcting this will remove your segfault.

But in order to print a wide string you'll need to correctly use the `%ls` modifier to `wprintf`.

Ultimately your code should look something like this:

```
wprintf(L"Attempting to compress %ls%ls\n", WorkingDirectory, File);

wchar_t FileRawInput[MAX_PATH];
wcsncpy(FileRawInput, WorkingDirectory, MAX_PATH);
wcsncat(FileRawInput, File, MAX_PATH);

wchar_t bzipCompressedOutput[MAX_PATH];
wcsncpy(bzipCompressedOutput, FileRawInput, MAX_PATH);
wcscat(bzipCompressedOutput, L".bz2");

wprintf(L"Output of string bzip: %ls\n", bzipCompressedOutput);
wprintf(L"Output of string raw: %ls\n", FileRawInput);
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/Xdu6zL)

**EDIT:**

The OP has acquiesced to Bjarne Stroustrup's advice and gone to `wstring`: [Concatenating char arrays together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439171/concatenating-char-arrays-together/37440210?noredirect=1#comment62383027_37440210) But for anyone else who is still insistent on using these C-Style functions, `MAX_PATH` must be large enough to accommodate `wsclen(WorkingDirectory) + wsclen(File) + wsclen(L".bz2")` plus the `L'\0'` character, so perhaps placing a if statement on this function would be useful or perhaps:

```
assert(MAX_PATH > wsclen(WorkingDirectory) + wsclen(File) + wsclen(L".bz2"))
```

Comment: I did fix my issue... but I took the suggestions above to move to strings. Heck, if the man himself is telling you to use strings, then you probably should. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: `sizeof(array)` is not the same as `sizeof(*)`. However, it does measure in bytes rather than units.

Comment: @rici I intended the `*` there to be either `FileRawInput` or `bzipCompressedOutput` but I see that was unclear. I have edited out my laziness.

Comment: Cool, +1. You missed the fact that the n in wcsn{cpy,cat} measure the source, not the destination, and that the destination needs to be one character longer for the NUL. As I suppose you probably know, `"%s"` in Microsoft's `wprintf` does expect a  const wchar_t*`, which differs from standard C where it would expect a `const char*` pointing at a multibyte string. So `"%ls"` is required with a standards-compliant standard library, and thus for portability, but on windows `"%s"` will, unfortunately, do what OP expects.

Comment: @rici I had assumed that `MAX_PATH` had accounted for that (maybe I should add a note on that.) The reason for the segfault was not because of insufficient space to write `FileRawInput` but insufficient space to write `sizeof(bzipCompressedOutput)` `wchar_t`s to `bzipCompressedOutput` when [`wcsncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcsncpy) executes: "If, after copying the terminating null wide character from `src`, `count` is not reached, additional null wide characters are written to `dest` until the total of `count` characters have been written."

Comment: @JonathanMee: Indeed that was the immediate problem. But even if that were fixed, providing the precise size of the output buffer as the argument to *ncpy leads to the possibility that the result is not NUL-terminated. The only safe way to do it is to allocate one extra character, which you explicitly initialize to NUL. *ncat, on the other hand, guarantees NUL-termination but since you supply the size of the source, it's your responsibility to ensure that the dest has room for the NUL. These functions are hard to use, and just adding the `n` doesn't make your program safe. On the contrary.

Comment: @rici I agree, this is why we use `wstring`s right? In the interest of completion I have appended the need for this check to the answer.